# Merge Sort Visualisation

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, mergesort, array-algorithms

```js
// variables
// arr has elements to be sorted
var arr = []
// temp is to store the intermediate results after merging
var temp = []
// seen is for marking visited i.e. sorted half as green
var seen = []
// length of array
var len = 100

// canvas initialisations
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
canvas.width = canvas.height = 1000
var canvaswidth = canvas.width
var canvasheight = canvas.height
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")

// random array
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 500))
    temp.push(parseInt(0))
    seen.push(parseInt(0))
}

// initial contents of array to be sorted
// console.log(arr)

// draw the bars
draw = (s, e) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)

    // this loop will make unvisited bars in the upper half as black
    // and visited bars in the upper half as green
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000"
        ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500 - arr[i], 10, arr[i])
        if (seen[i]) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"
            ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500 - arr[i], 10, arr[i])
        }
    }

    // the part that was merged is made blue in the lower half
    // also its equivalent in the uper half is made white
    for (let i = s; i <= e; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff"
        ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500 - arr[i], 10, arr[i])
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0000ff"
        ctx.fillRect(15 * i, 500, 10, arr[i])
        seen[i] = 1
    }

}

// merge
merge = (s, e) => {

    let m = parseInt((s + e) / 2)
    let p1 = s
    let p2 = m + 1
    let n1 = m
    let n2 = e
    let idx = s

    while (p1 <= n1 && p2 <= n2) {
        if (arr[p1] <= arr[p2]) {
            temp[idx++] = arr[p1++]
        }
        else {
            temp[idx++] = arr[p2++]
        }
    }

    while (p1 <= n1) {
        temp[idx++] = arr[p1++]
    }

    while (p2 <= n2) {
        temp[idx++] = arr[p2++]
    }

    idx = s
    while (idx <= e) {
        arr[idx] = temp[idx++]
    }

}

// delay
function mytimeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// mergesort
const mergesort = async (s, e) => {

    if (s < e) {
        let m = parseInt((s + e) / 2)
        await mergesort(s, m)
        await mergesort(m + 1, e)
        await merge(s, e)
        // await console.log(`merged ${s} to ${e} now draw...`)
        await draw(s, e)
        await mytimeout(500)
    }

}

// calls merge sort and at last 
// makes all bars become green in upper half
const performer = async () => {
    await mergesort(0, len - 1)
    // await console.log(arr)
    await draw()
}



performer()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas">
        Your browser does not support the canvas element.
    </canvas>
    <script src="testmerge.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to make a visualisation of **merge sort** using plain javascript with HTML canvas.

If i change the len variable to 50 or below my code works

currently i have kept the len variable at 100

the entire array after getting sorted, in the final picture, the bars in the histogram decrease in height automatically

i am not sure if there is a better/cleaner way to approach this

Comment: You seem to ask two questions: (1) how to improve the working code, as presented in the question (2) solve the problem for larger array sizes. Please note that you should only ask one question, and that (1) is more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). For (2) please provide the necessary (but minimal) code to reproduce the problem *embedded* in the question (use snippet button), not behind a link.

Comment: thankyou! and sorry for posting it here.

Comment: the part i have issue in is the part i have included as a snippet

Comment: That part of the code looks fine. But it has dependencies. Can you create a runnable snippet (using the snippet toolbar button) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: ya done.. now if i change the 'len' variable in javascript to above 50 i.e.e 75 100 etc, the code doesnt quite behave as expected.. i cannot understand why

Comment: Then it would be good if you put that offending len value in your snippet, so it *demonstrates* the issue. Also "doesn't quite behave as expected" is vague. Please can you add one phrase in your question that explains exactly what goes wrong, and what the expected behaviour is?

Comment: done. now i have kept the len variable at 100 for you to view the issue

Comment: @Peilonrayz, the reasons for the close votes are given there in comments. Of course, it was not my suggestion to put question (2) there, because that is off-topic there, and on-topic here. The OP just asks two questions there, which is making the same mistake as here. I don't understand how I could have been more clear...

Comment: Second attempt: Don't ask two questions. You have two questions: Question (1) is about improving working code, making it better/cleaner. That question is off-topic here, and Code Review is better suited for that. Question (2) is about a problem that occurs for larger array sizes. It is on topic here, provided that the code is included to reproduce the problem (this has been done in the mean time).

Comment: @trincot Was that meant to ping me? Do you want to know if that is unlikely to be misunderstood? I can't tell you if I would misunderstand it as I already know what you mean. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There is a visual glitch because the width of your canvas element is fixed to 1000 pixels, and the bars always have a width of 10 pixels with 5 pixel gaps between them. This means that the bar chart gets clipped as soon as the number of bars gets too large to fit in those 1000 pixels.

One way to fix this is to make the width of the bars (and the inter-gap) dynamically smaller as the number of bars increases.

Here is a fix, which introduces the variables `bardistance`, `barwidth` and `bargap`, although the latter is only there to pinpoint what the gap-value is: it is not used in the rest of the code.

```js
// variables
// arr has elements to be sorted
var arr = [];
// temp is to store the intermediate results after merging
var temp = [];
// seen is for marking visited i.e. sorted half as green
var seen = [];
// length of array
var len = 100;

// canvas initialisations
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 1000;
var canvaswidth = canvas.width;
var canvasheight = canvas.height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var bardistance = Math.floor(canvaswidth / len);
if (!bardistance) bardistance = 1;
var barwidth = Math.floor(bardistance * 0.7);
if (!barwidth) barwidth = 1;
var bargap = bardistance - barwidth;

// random array
for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(parseInt(Math.random() * 500));
    temp.push(parseInt(0));
    seen.push(parseInt(0));
}

// initial contents of array to be sorted
// console.log(arr)

// draw the bars
var draw = (s, e) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

    // this loop will make unvisited bars in the upper half as black
    // and visited bars in the upper half as green
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillRect(bardistance * i, 500 - arr[i], barwidth, arr[i]);
        if (seen[i]) {
            ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00";
            ctx.fillRect(bardistance * i, 500 - arr[i], barwidth, arr[i]);
        }
    }

    // the part that was merged is made blue in the lower half
    // also its equivalent in the uper half is made white
    for (let i = s; i <= e; i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        ctx.fillRect(bardistance * i, 500 - arr[i], barwidth, arr[i]);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
        ctx.fillRect(bardistance * i, 500, barwidth, arr[i]);
        seen[i] = 1;
    }

}

// merge
merge = (s, e) => {

    let m = parseInt((s + e) / 2);
    let p1 = s;
    let p2 = m + 1;
    let n1 = m;
    let n2 = e;
    let idx = s;

    while (p1 <= n1 && p2 <= n2) {
        if (arr[p1] <= arr[p2]) {
            temp[idx++] = arr[p1++];
        }
        else {
            temp[idx++] = arr[p2++];
        }
    }

    while (p1 <= n1) {
        temp[idx++] = arr[p1++];
    }

    while (p2 <= n2) {
        temp[idx++] = arr[p2++];
    }

    idx = s;
    while (idx <= e) {
        arr[idx] = temp[idx++];
    }

}

// delay
function mytimeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

// mergesort
const mergesort = async (s, e) => {

    if (s < e) {
        let m = parseInt((s + e) / 2);
        await mergesort(s, m);
        await mergesort(m + 1, e);
        await merge(s, e);
        // await console.log(`merged ${s} to ${e} now draw...`)
        await draw(s, e);
        await mytimeout(500);
    }

}

// calls merge sort and at last 
// makes all bars become green in upper half
const performer = async () => {
    await mergesort(0, len - 1);
    // await console.log(arr)
    await draw();
}

performer();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```